# Configure all popup editor buttons in KendoGrid to display 'Save' or 'Add' instead of 'Update'

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In a popup editor in KendoGrid, the default buttons (if not specified), are "Update" and "Cancel".

If you have a lot of popup editors in different pages, does Kendo provide a specific config file where we can write scripts that all popup editors must have a button of "Save" or "Add" and "Cancel" instead of having "Update" and "Cancel"?

Answer (score 1):

You can get at these at runtime per control with `kendo.ui.<Widget-name>.prototype.options.messages` and in the source at `src/messages/kendo.messages.en-US.js`.  (en-US just an example, see the section on [localization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/localization/overview) )